# std::mem_fn with ref_qualified member functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way by which we can make use of ref qualified member functions with `std::mem_fn` ?

The below code fails to compile:

```
class DeadPool {
public:
  void jump() & {
    std::cout << "Did not jump\n";
  }

  void jump() && {
    std::cout << "Jumped from helicopter\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  DeadPool dp1;
  //auto cobj = std::mem_fn(&DeadPool::jump); // Won't compile
  //cobj(dp1);
  //cobj(DeadPool());
  using Func = void (DeadPool::*) () &; // lvalue ref qualifier explicitly provided
  Func fp = &DeadPool::jump; // This works, as expected
  (std::move(dp1).*fp)();
  return 0;
}
```

Error message:

> mem_fn_ex.cc:18:15: error: no matching function for call to 'mem_fn'
>   auto cobj = std::mem_fn(&DeadPool::jump); // Won't compile
>                 ^~~~~~~~~~~ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:1233:1:
>   note: candidate
>         template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Rp' mem_fn(_Rp _Tp::* __pm) ^ mem_fn_ex.cc:23:18: error: pointer-to-member
>   function type 'Func' (aka 'void (DeadPool::*)() &') can
>         only be called on an lvalue   (std::move(dp1).*fp)();    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

Compiler: On both Clang(3.4) and g++ (5.3)

I thought I could make use of the fact that, in `std::_Mem_fn` class implementation an rvalue object is invoked like below:

```
return (std::move(__object).*__pmf)(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

This could have very well invoked the member function specific for rvalue `this`, but since the signatures are different at compile time, it cannot do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing an overloaded function into a function template - `mem_fn()` can't deduce *which* `jump()` you want. You would need to pass a specific one with a cast:

```
auto cobj = std::mem_fn(static_cast<void (DeadPool::*)() &>(&DeadPool::jump));
cobj(dp1);        // ok
cobj(DeadPool()); // error
```

However, that's a really unsatisfying solution due to both the verbosity (that's a LOT to type) and the limitations (you have `&`- and `&&`-qualified overloads for a reason, but you can only use one?). Better to use a generic lambda here:

```
auto jump = [](auto&& pool){ std::forward<decltype(pool)>(pool).jump(); };
jump(dp1);         // ok: Did not jump
jump(DeadPool());  // ok: Jumped from helicopter
```

Comment: This makes me think why `this` is not overloaded based on the ref qualifier instead. Any idea ?

Comment: @Arunmu What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: Well, if the compiler implemented it in that way, the code in question would have probably worked.

Comment: @Arunmu No, it wouldn't have. The code in the question doesn't work because the the compiler can't deduce a type for `&DeadPool::jump` (that's an overloaded name - there is no single type to be deduced).